# can the component be called stateful component without having state object

Tags: reactjs

I was asked in an interview that whether the below example can still be called a stateful component, even though there's no state object used inside it. Below is an example where we increment the count on every click without using state object to keep the previous value,

index.js

```
     let model = { clicks: 0 };

     function render() {
       ReactDOM.render(
         <App
           clicks={model.clicks}
           onClick={() => {
           model.clicks += 1;
           render();
         }}
      />,
     document.getElementById("root")
    );
   }
   render();
```

app.js

```
      class App extends Component {
       render() {
          return (
             <div className="App" onClick={this.props.onClick}>
                This div is clicked {this.props.clicks} times
            </div>
          );
         }
       }
 export default App;
```

Comment: I'd say it's okay to call it a stateful component because while it is true that you're not using the state object to maintain the state you're still managing the state using a javascript object and passing it down.

Comment: React's definition of a "stateful component", or the more generic programming definition of internal  "instance" type variable declarations? No to the former, yes to the latter. Hopefully you asked good questions to resolve any ambiguity.